# CartoDB Point Clustering?

Tags: carto, clustering

I need to create clusters in Cartodb. I reffered to this code https://gist.github.com/andrewxhill/8695353. I am still getting an error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--Edit the title of the page-->
    <title>CartoDB Point Clustering</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/themes/css/cartodb.css" />
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/themes/css/cartodb.ie.css" />
    <![endif]-->
    <!--Switch between the different themes changing the stylesheet below - light-theme.css |dark-theme.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <style type="text/css">

    * Change the styles below in order to customize your template */

body{font-family: Helvetica, Arial; font-weight: regular; font-size: 15px; color: #555; background-color: #FFF; margin: 0;}
h1{font-weight: bold; font-size: 31px; letter-spacing: -1px; color: #333; line-height: 33px;}
h3{font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; color: #CCC; text-transform: uppercase; margin: 10px 0 0 0;}
p{margin: 8px 0 20px 0; line-height: 18px;}
a, a:visited{color: #397DB8; text-decoration: none;}
a:hover{text-decoration: underline;}

.wrapper{display: block; padding: 4px 30px 0 30px;}

.map{background-color:#eee; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; width: 67%; *height:100%;}
.sidepanel{background-color:#FFF; position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; width: 33%; height: 100%; overflow: auto;}

.context{font-family: Helvetica, Arial; font-size: 13px; color: #999; padding: 10px 0 0 0;}
.subheader{border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;}
.footer{border-top: 1px solid #ddd; margin-top: 30px;}
.titleBlock{text-align: right;}

/* Here are the styles that makes the template responsive */

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .map{position: inherit; height: 400px; width: 100%; display: block;}
  .sidepanel{position: inherit; width: 100%;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .map {height: 300px;}
}
      .here ul {list-style: none;}
      .here ul li {list-style: none; margin: 2px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="map" id="map"></div>

    <div class="sidepanel">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="context subheader">

        </div>
        <h1>Point clustering</h1>
        <p>This is a demonstration of point clustering using <a href="http://cartodb.com">CartoDB</a>. The method uses an advanced mix of SQL, CartoCSS, and CartoDB.js, continue at your own risk...</p>
        <p><label for="size">Cluster size</label> [<span class="size">48</span>]: <input type="range" name="size" id="cluster_size" value="48" min="20" max="60" step="2"></p>
        <!--Copy and paste the div below for creating content blocks-->
        <h3 class="here-title">What's here?</h3>
        <div class="here">Click a point to find out!</div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3.8"></script>
    <script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/cartodb.js"></script>


    <script type="sql/html" id="sql_template">
    WITH metatile_extent AS (
      SELECT ST_SetSRID(!bbox!::box3d, 3857) as ext
    ),

    filtered_table AS (
      SELECT t.* FROM surveys_view t, metatile_extent m WHERE t.the_geom_webmercator && m.ext
    ),
    hgridA AS (SELECT CDB_HexagonGrid(ST_Expand(!bbox!, greatest(!pixel_width!,!pixel_height!) * {0}), greatest(!pixel_width!,!pixel_height!) * {0}) as cell),
        bigs AS (SELECT * FROM (SELECT ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(i.the_geom_webmercator)) as the_geom_webmercator, count(i.cartodb_id) as points_count, 1 as cartodb_id, array_agg(cartodb_id) AS id_list FROM hgridA, filtered_table i where ST_Intersects(i.the_geom_webmercator, hgridA.cell) GROUP BY hgridA.cell) t WHERE points_count > 2*{0} ),
        hgridB AS (SELECT CDB_HexagonGrid(ST_Expand(!bbox!, greatest(!pixel_width!,!pixel_height!) * 0.75*{0}), greatest(!pixel_width!,!pixel_height!) * 0.75*{0}) as cell),
        mids AS (SELECT * FROM (SELECT ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(i.the_geom_webmercator)) as the_geom_webmercator, count(i.cartodb_id) as points_count, 1 as cartodb_id, array_agg(cartodb_id) AS id_list FROM hgridB, filtered_table i where ST_Intersects(i.the_geom_webmercator, hgridB.cell) AND cartodb_id NOT IN (SELECT unnest(id_list) FROM bigs) GROUP BY hgridB.cell) t WHERE points_count > 0.5*{0} ),
        hgridC AS (SELECT CDB_HexagonGrid(ST_Expand(!bbox!, greatest(!pixel_width!,!pixel_height!) * 24), greatest(!pixel_width!,!pixel_height!) * 0.5*{0}) as cell),
        smalls AS (SELECT * FROM (SELECT ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(i.the_geom_webmercator)) as the_geom_webmercator, count(i.cartodb_id) as points_count, 1 as cartodb_id, array_agg(cartodb_id) AS id_list FROM hgridC, filtered_table i where ST_Intersects(i.the_geom_webmercator, hgridC.cell) AND cartodb_id NOT IN (SELECT unnest(id_list) FROM bigs) AND cartodb_id NOT IN (SELECT unnest(id_list) FROM mids) GROUP BY hgridC.cell) t WHERE points_count > GREATEST(0.1*{0}, 2) )
        SELECT the_geom_webmercator, 1 points_count, cartodb_id, ARRAY[cartodb_id] as id_list, 'origin' as src, cartodb_id::text cdb_list FROM filtered_table WHERE cartodb_id NOT IN (select unnest(id_list) FROM bigs) AND cartodb_id NOT IN (select unnest(id_list) FROM mids) AND cartodb_id NOT IN (select unnest(id_list) FROM smalls)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT *, 'bigs' as src, array_to_string(id_list, ',') FROM bigs
        UNION ALL
        SELECT *, 'mids' as src, array_to_string(id_list, ',') FROM mids
        UNION ALL
        SELECT *, 'smalls' as src, array_to_string(id_list, ',') FROM smalls
    </script>
    <script type="sql/html" id ="cartocss_template">
      #layer {
        marker-width: {0} * 0.15;
        marker-fill: #5CA2D1;
        marker-opacity: 0.6;
        marker-line-width: 0;
        marker-allow-overlap: true;
        marker-comp-op: dst-atop;
        [src = 'smalls'] {marker-width: {0} * 0.35; }
        [src = 'mids'] {marker-width: {0} * 0.7;}
        [src = 'bigs'] { marker-width: {0} * 1.4; }
        [zoom>11]{marker-width: {0};}
      }
      #layer::lables {
        text-size: 0;
        text-fill: black;
        text-opacity: 0.8;
        text-name: [points_count];
        text-face-name: 'DejaVu Sans Book';
        text-halo-fill: #fff;
        text-halo-radius: 0;
        // if points_count >= 100 we should also make text smaller //
        [src = 'smalls'] {text-size: {0} * 0.2; text-halo-radius: 1; }
        // if points_count >= 1000 we should also make text smaller //
        [src = 'mids'] {text-size: {0} * 0.3; text-halo-radius: 1; }
        // if points_count >= 10000 we should also make text smaller //
        [src = 'bigs'] { text-size: {0} * 0.5; text-halo-radius: 1; }
        text-allow-overlap: true;
        [zoom>11]{text-size: {0} * 0.66;}
      }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map;

      function addCursorInteraction(layer) {
        var hovers = [];

        layer.bind('featureOver', function(e, latlon, pxPos, data, layer) {
          hovers[layer] = 1;
          if(_.any(hovers)) {
            $('#map').css('cursor', 'pointer');
          }
        });

        layer.bind('featureOut', function(m, layer) {
          hovers[layer] = 0;
          if(!_.any(hovers)) {
            $('#map').css('cursor', 'auto');
          }
        });


        layer.bind('featureClick', function(e, latlon, pxPos, data, layer) {
          var list = data['cdb_list'].split(',');
          if (list.length > 1){
            $('.here-title').html(list.length+" features:");
            $('.here').html("<ul></ul>");
            for (i in list){
              $(".here ul").append('<li><a href="#'+list[i]+'" class="cartodb_id" id="'+list[i]+'">'+list[i]+'</a></li></li>');
            }

            $('.cartodb_id').on('click', function(){

              $.get("http://nisha.cartodb.com/api/v1/sql?q=select cartodb_id,ST_X(the_geom) lon, ST_Y(the_geom) lat from surveys_view WHERE cartodb_id = " + $(this).attr('id'), function(ret) {

                var lat = ret.rows[0].lat; delete ret.rows[0].lat;
                var lon = ret.rows[0].lon; delete ret.rows[0].lon;
                map.setView(new L.LatLng(lat, lon), 12);

                $('.here-title').html("");
                $('.here').html("");
                for (i in ret.rows[0]){
                  $('.here').append("<h3>"+i+"</h3>");
                  $('.here').append(ret.rows[0][i]);
                }
              });
              //zoom to 11
            })

          } else {
            $('.here-title').html("");
            $('.here').html("");
            $.get("http://nisha.cartodb.com/api/v1/sql?q=select cartodb_id from surveys_view WHERE cartodb_id = " + data['cartodb_id'], function(ret) {
              for (i in ret.rows[0]){
                $('.here').append("<h3>"+i+"</h3>");
                $('.here').append(ret.rows[0][i]);
              }
            });
          }
        });


      }

      function main() {

        // create leaflet map
        map = L.map('map', {
          zoomControl: true,
          center: [35, -85],
          zoom: 6
        })

        // add a base layer
        L.tileLayer('http://tile.stamen.com/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
          attribution: 'Stamen'
        }).addTo(map);
        var layerUrl= 'http://nisha.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/990a1570-3b0b-11e4-9b02-0e73339ffa50/viz.json' ;

        var gridsize = 48;
        var baseSql = $('#sql_template').html().format(gridsize);
        var cartoCss = $('#cartocss_template').html().format(gridsize);
        var sublayer;
        $("#cluster_size").on('change',function(){
          $('.size').html($("#cluster_size").val());
        });
        $("#cluster_size").on('mouseup',function(){
          sublayer.setSQL($('#sql_template').html().format($("#cluster_size").val()));
          sublayer.setCartoCSS($('#cartocss_template').html().format($("#cluster_size").val()))
        });
        // add cartodb layer with one sublayer
        cartodb.createLayer(map, {
          user_name: 'andrew',
          type: 'cartodb',
          sublayers: [{
             sql: baseSql,
             cartocss: cartoCss,
             interactivity: 'cartodb_id, cdb_list'
          }]
        })
        .addTo(map)
        .done(function(layer) {
          sublayer = layer.getSubLayer(0);
          sublayer.setInteraction(true);
          addCursorInteraction(sublayer);
        });


      }

      String.prototype.format = (function (i, safe, arg) {
            function format() {
                var str = this,
                    len = arguments.length + 1;

                for (i = 0; i < len; arg = arguments[i++]) {
                    safe = typeof arg === 'object' ? JSON.stringify(arg) : arg;
                    str = str.replace(RegExp('\\{' + (i - 1) + '\\}', 'g'), safe);
                }
                return str;
            }

            //format.native = String.prototype.format;
            return format;
        })();
      // you could use $(window).load(main);
      window.onload = main;
    </script>

  </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: What is your error? Could you post the error message or screenshot for potential answerers please?

Answer (score 2):

Switch out the user name. That should do it.

```
// add cartodb layer with one sublayer
    cartodb.createLayer(map, {
      user_name: 'your_user_name'
```